# simple webpage for text conversion

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am just starting web programming with javascript and php.
I am trying to build a webpage that would accept text pasted in a form on upper half of page and on the press of a button show the processed text ( could be any type of text processing lets say removing all occurances of letter m from the text ).
i can you guide me to a link on the net to understand what kind of coding would be required in such a webpage ?

what kind of basics of php / javascript should be understood before trying out this page ?

thanks

Comment: If you do not need to store the information in a persistence system (database) and just want to process the text to display on your Web page, you do not need PHP.

Comment: You do not php for this stuff. Plain old java script is enough .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight - that does depend on the nature of the processing. In the given example, its true, but that was specifically given as an example. And if the aim of the exercise is to learn how to use PHP to process form input then saying "you don't need PHP" isn't really very helpful. Perhaps point to some tutorials instead?

Comment: @SDC: That was not what the question was about. The question was asked  with respect to an exercise. My answer was w.r.t that. If the OP would have wanted to know about PHP, he could have asked that instead in the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with jQuery ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/wdh8z/)). Read all about jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/)

HTML

```
<input type='textarea'>
<hr />
<div id="transfer">Click for copy</div>
<hr />
<div id="thecopy"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#transfer').click(function(){
    $('#thecopy').text($('input').val());
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript like this

HTML code

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="buttom" onclick="do_process();" value="Process" />
```

JavaScript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function do_process() {
       var data = document.getElementById("name").value;
       var processed_data = here put processing function whatever you want;
       document.getElementById("name").value = processed_data;
    }
</script>
```